# 同一LANの機器にグローバルIPを指定して接続することはできますか？

Tags: network

同一のLANに接続された機器、A・Bがあるとして、AからBにグローバルIPを指定して接続することは出来ますか？プライベートIPを指定した場合は通信出来るのですが、グローバルIPを指定した場合は接続出来ないという状況です。
ルータのポートが閉じているが原因かと思い設定をしてみたのですが解決しません。
原理的に同一LANの機器にグローバルIPを指定して接続することは出来ない、ということはないでしょうか？

恐らくルータのポート開放の設定が上手くいってないのだと思ってますが、質問したようなことはないと思いつつも確認のために質問した次第です。

Comment: 今の説明では読者には状況が把握できないので、もうちょっと詳しい説明が欲しいです。この場合のグローバルIP(アドレス) ってどのマシンが保有しているとかどうとか。　まあ普通には「できない」んですけど。

Comment: プライベートIPで繋がっているのに、あえてグローバルIP経由で通信したい理由は何でしょうか？ ( [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/3060) に陥っている可能性も) / 一般的な「静的アドレス変換」はポート番号で割当を行うので、同じポート番号を使用しているとうまくいかないかもしれません。

Comment: プライベートIPでつながってるのに、グローバルIP経由で通信したいのは、プライベートIPの使用はテスト環境での話で、本番環境ではグローバルIP経由で通信するからです。ちなみに、IPマスカレードが原因かと思い、静的IPマスカレードに設定しましたが、効果なしでした

Comment: 機器、という表現はややこしかったです。ここでいう機器とはPCやスマホのことで、今回はそれ上で動くアプリ間での通信を想定していました。

Comment: 似たような状況で静的ルーティングなどを設定して実現したような覚えがあります。何年も前の話で詳細は覚えてないですが。AとBのOSとか、イーサネットが何本繋がっているとか、そういう情報も必要かと思います。

Comment: 機器A,機器Bのグローバルアドレス（WAN側アドレス？）はIPv4下だと同じ値（ルーターのWAN側アドレス）になっていないか確認ください。グローバルアドレスだけではLAN内の個別機器を指定するのは不可能なのではないかと思われ、そのためにルーターにポートフォワーディングで、グローバルアドレス：ポート番号宛てのパケットをローカルアドレス：ポート番号に転送しなさいというテーブルを設定する必要があると思っているのですが

Comment: int32_tさんと同じく、ルーティングテーブルを設定することで解決しそうに思われますが、ルーティングテーブルの設定が許可されている環境かどうかは質問文からは判断できませんね。

Answer (score 4):

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

こんな環境で、AからBにルータの外側についてるアドレスを使ってアクセスしたい、という話だと理解しました。

まず、ルータの設定で、いわゆる「ポート転送」とか「ポート開放」とか言われる設定をすることで、インターネット側から機器Bにアクセスすることは(大抵)可能です。

これが、LAN内の機器同士、すなわち、機器AはグローバルIPアドレス宛てに接続し、よしなにアドレス変換され実際にはBと通信する、ということができるかどうかは、ルータの機器仕様次第です。メーカーのサポートに確認されるのがよいでしょう。このような折り返しの通信でNATしようとする通信形態が、俗にヘアピンNATと呼ばれるものです。

やりたいことが具体的には書かれていないのでニーズに合っているかはわかりませんが、NATではなく名前解決でクリアできないでしょうか。

外向きのDNSにはグローバルIPアドレスを登録しておき、内向きのDNSまたは機器AのhostsにはローカルのIPアドレスを書いておけば、同じホスト名でインターネットからも内部からも接続できることになります。ホスト名ベースでの通信であればこちらで手法のほうが一般的だと思います。

Answer (score 3):

通りすがりにスミマセン。
これっていわゆる「ヘアピンNAT」とか言われることを
実現したいというご質問でしょうか。であれば上記
キーワードで検索していただくといろいろ情報が
得られるかと思います。
可否については、機器の仕様と設定に依ります。